# A package dependency has the wrong name

Tags: fedora, package-management

I have to install the package [polychromatic](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=hardware%3Arazer&package=polychromatic).

When I run the command `dnf install polychromatic`, I get the following error:

```
Error: nothing provides imagemagick needed by polychromatic-0.3.8-2.1.noarch
```

However, I've installed `imagemagick` following this guide: [ImageMagick - image manipulation tool rhel/centos/fedora](https://www.linuxhelp.com/install-imagemagick-image-manipulation-tool-rhelcentos-fedora/)

This guide allows me to install the packages `ImageMagick`, `ImageMagick-devel`, `ImageMagick-perl`. And here is the problem, I guess: polychromatic is looking for `imagemagick` rather than `ImageMagick`. How can I specify, during the installation, that it should look for `ImageMagick` rather than `imagemagick`?

Comment: As far as I know you can't without modifying the source package and rebuilding. It is a problem of the package creator and you should talk to him to get that fixed (because it is obviously wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the spec file, and as of version 0.3.12-9.6 is already fixed.

If you encounter something like this in the future, here's how to fix this:

1. Download the `src.rpm` package (in the link provided in the original question, choose your operating system then click "Grab Binary packages directly".
2. Make sure the RPM build tools are installed: `dnf install rpm-build rpmdevtools yum-utils wget`
3. Deploy the source RPM package: `rpm -i polychromatic*.src.rpm`. This will extract the files in the source RPM package into the `~/rpmbuild` - which may need to be created: follow the notifications on the screen and create any missing directories.
4. Edit the package specification file at `~/rpmbuild/SPECS/polychromatic.spec` and change the relevant `Requires:` definitions to be what it should be.
5. Download required source files: `spectool -g -R ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/polychromatic.spec`
6. Download and install build requirements: `yum-builddep -y ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/polychromatic.spec`
7. Build new binary packages: `rpmbuild -bb ~/rpmbuild/polychromatic.spec`
8. Install the new packages: `dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/polychromatic*.rpm`